# python-docx-template and {%tr for a loop and if condition error

Tags: django, jinja2

I'm using the python package python-docx-template in a django project.

I'm trying to build a table with a condition to display some rows. I'm trying to nest a '{%tr' of an if statement in a 'for' loop one :
[image: nested tr]

This lead to an error :

> emplateSyntaxError at /reports/employee/73/2/
>
> Encountered unknown tag 'tr'. Jinja was looking for the following
> tags: 'endfor' or 'else'. The innermost block that needs to be closed
> is 'for'.

1/  If I remove the 'tr' of the 'if' statement, all works great, but it print empty rows (those of the 'if' and 'endif').

2/  If I remove the 'tr' of the 'for' loop (so keep the one of the 'if'), I've got the error :

> Encountered unknown tag 'tr'. Jinja was looking for the following
> tags: 'endfor' or 'else'. The innermost block that needs to be closed
> is 'for'.

I can not modify datas send to render the template.
How can I conditionally print those rows?